# passing a non specific class into another class

Tags: java, android

I found myself writing this part of code over and over again in all of the fragments:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            if (bundle == null) {
                return null;
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Map<String, String>> data = (List<Map<String, String>>) bundle.getSerializable("data");
            / ........../
    }

}
```

I'm not sure how to refactor it into a class to avoid repetition. I'm getting an error passing the reference of a class (It could be Tab1 or Tab2 or Tab3)into it:

```
public class GetBundle {

    public <T> T serialize(Class clazz,String key){
        Bundle bundle = clazz.getArguments();
                        ^^^^ 
        if (bundle == null) {
            return null;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T data = (T) bundle.getSerializable(key);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `serialize` method,`Class` type doesn't have method `getArguments`,so you should change `clazz` type to `Fragment`.

Like this:

```
public <T> T serialize(Fragment clazz,String key){
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't apply the fix you are suggesting.